# Umbraco skin button not showing in UI

Tags: user-interface, button, content-management-system, umbraco, skin

I've linked the skin to the template where I want to use the skin but when I want to edit the skin the button to edit is not showing.

Thanks in advance
Thijs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this one. The solution is [here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/24642-Skin-button-not-showing-in-UI?p=0#comment91543)

> I solved this one, even though I think the're more suitable solutions.
>   Since you can skin starters kits out of the box I added my
>   masterpage-template id to the templates of the starters kit in
>   'App_data/packages/installed/installedPackages.config' and linked the
>   custom skin I created in the masterpages folder like they show on the
>   videos.